# Mouse tracking of page - and displaying it

Tags: javascript, css, html

Basically I am trying to create a little image at the top corner of a webpage, which would stay in the same position even if the page is scrolled and would show the position of the mouse.

The point is to have a large webpage that would extend down and right, and navigation of this large page would be easier if I had a little image that indicated where exactly the visitor is on this page (as the browser window is smaller than the page). I wanted to to just track the browser window position on the web page, but I cannot find anything that would help me do it, so I thought I might do it with just the mouse movement. The problem is that I know about nothing about java, so does anyone know how I could track the mouse position on the page (not the browser) and display it at the same time on a small image on the upper corner of the browser?

Comment: What does that have to do with java? Yu can do it using javascript!

Comment: Basically sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but only in modern browsers that support css3 transforms (scale):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/TS2tc/2/)

It works by copying the whole page that should be in the .actual-page div into a .thumbnail div which is positioned on the top left of the page. Then I scale the cloned page with css transforms and use javascript to replicate mouse movements into the little box, here's the script:

```
var TinyNav = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        var clone = $('.actual-page').clone();
        $('.thumbnail').append(clone);
        $('.actual-page').on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var posX = e.offsetX;
            var posY = e.offsetY;
            $('.thumbnail .cursor').css({
                top: posY / 10,
                left: posX / 10
            });
        });
    }

    this.init();
}

var tinyNav = new TinyNav();
```

Another way of doing it  would be using canvas, but browser support isn't the best with that either..
Hope this helps